# Google Calendar Integration w/ Oracle APEX

Tags: google-calendar-api, oracle-apex

I just started programming with SQL and thought to take on Oracle APEX as my first environment.  To better understand Dynamic Actions, I also tried to pick up my first project of accessing the Google Calendar API and using it to make an event in my own Google Calendar.  I was able to successfully establish authentication, however when I tried to actually create or return an event, nothing happened and no event was created in my Google Calendar.

Fearing it might be an issue with the code, I set up a node server and was able to both create events and return them with ease.  I was curious as to why this occurred and what possible solutions there may be to the problem.  The research I did led me to an outdated plugin which could possibly serve as a workaround, a tutorial attached to the outdated plugin, a tutorial that used non existent features, and a rather confusing oracle forums post, none of which helped me understand or solve my issue.

If anyone is knowledgeable enough to help identify the problem or the solution, I would greatly appreciate it as even my friends who have more experience with APEX and programming in general have been stumped!  I'll provide the code I used for the node server just in case that  will end up being useful:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      // Your Client ID can be retrieved from your project in the Google
      // Developer Console, https://console.developers.google.com
      var CLIENT_ID = '(--redacted--)';

      var SCOPES = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly"];

      /**
       * Check if current user has authorized this application.
       */
      function checkAuth() {
        gapi.auth.authorize(
          {
            'client_id': CLIENT_ID,
            'scope': SCOPES.join(' '),
            'immediate': true
          }, handleAuthResult);
      }

      /**
       * Handle response from authorization server.
       *
       * @param {Object} authResult Authorization result.
       */
      function handleAuthResult(authResult) {
        var authorizeDiv = document.getElementById('authorize-div');
        if (authResult && !authResult.error) {
          // Hide auth UI, then load client library.
          authorizeDiv.style.display = 'none';
          loadCalendarApi();
        } else {
          // Show auth UI, allowing the user to initiate authorization by
          // clicking authorize button.
          authorizeDiv.style.display = 'inline';
        }
      }

      /**
       * Initiate auth flow in response to user clicking authorize button.
       *
       * @param {Event} event Button click event.
       */
      function handleAuthClick(event) {
        gapi.auth.authorize(
          {client_id: CLIENT_ID, scope: SCOPES, immediate: false},
          handleAuthResult);
        return false;
      }

      /**
       * Load Google Calendar client library. List upcoming events
       * once client library is loaded.
       */
      function loadCalendarApi() {
        gapi.client.load('calendar', 'v3', listUpcomingEvents);
      }

      /**
       * Print the summary and start datetime/date of the next ten events in
       * the authorized user's calendar. If no events are found an
       * appropriate message is printed.
       */
      function listUpcomingEvents() {
        var request = gapi.client.calendar.events.list({
          'calendarId': 'primary',
          'timeMin': (new Date()).toISOString(),
          'showDeleted': false,
          'singleEvents': true,
          'maxResults': 10,
          'orderBy': 'startTime'
        });

        request.execute(function(resp) {
          var events = resp.items;
          appendPre('Upcoming events:');

          if (events.length > 0) {
            for (i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {
              var event = events[i];
              var when = event.start.dateTime;
              if (!when) {
                when = event.start.date;
              }
              appendPre(event.summary + ' (' + when + ')')
            }
          } else {
            appendPre('No upcoming events found.');
          }

        });
      }

      /**
       * Append a pre element to the body containing the given message
       * as its text node.
       *
       * @param {string} message Text to be placed in pre element.
       */
      function appendPre(message) {
        var pre = document.getElementById('output');
        var textContent = document.createTextNode(message + '\n');
        pre.appendChild(textContent);
      }

    function createEventMaster() {
    var event = {
  'summary': 'Google I/O 2015',
  'location': '800 Howard St., San Francisco, CA 94103',
  'description': 'A chance to hear more about Google\'s developer 
products.',
  'start': {
    'dateTime': '2016-06-05T09:00:00-07:00',
    'timeZone': 'America/Los_Angeles'
  },
  'end': {
    'dateTime': '2016-06-06T17:00:00-07:00',
    'timeZone': 'America/Los_Angeles'
  },
  'recurrence': [
    'RRULE:FREQ=DAILY;COUNT=2'
  ],
  'reminders': {
    'useDefault': false,
    'overrides': [
      {'method': 'email', 'minutes': 24 * 60},
      {'method': 'popup', 'minutes': 10}
    ]
  }
};

var request = gapi.client.calendar.events.insert({
  'calendarId': 'primary',
  'resource': event
});

request.execute(function(event) {
  appendPre('Event created: ' + event.htmlLink);
});
    }
    </script>
    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=checkAuth">
    console.log('test');
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
<button id="test" onclick="createEventMaster()"> create event </button>
    <div id="authorize-div" style="display: none">
      <span>Authorize access to Google Calendar API</span>
      <!--Button for the user to click to initiate auth sequence -->
      <button id="authorize-button" onclick="handleAuthClick(event)">
        Authorize
      </button>
    </div>
    <pre id="output"></pre>
  </body>
</html>
```

TL;DR Oracle APEX won't create google calendar events, same code entered into a node server will, why is this the case?

Comment: Have you tried debugging the response you get from the API call to Google?

Comment: It could be a problem with same-origin policy? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy

Comment: The issue, and what is probably due to my own inexperience with the APEX environment, is that it doesn't seem to return an error of any type!  Debugging doesn't seem to bring up anything which leads me to believe the actions are being carried out but not actually being executed???  I'm not sure if this is possible and I apologize if this doesn't provide that much information since I don't have too good of an idea of what I'm doing!  I think that the link you posted might be exactly what I'm experiencing and even if it's not, I really appreciate the help!  Thanks!